# Dagger2 can't see method with @Provide annotation defined in other module. Cannot be provided without an @provides-annotated method

Tags: java, android, mvvm, dependency-injection, dagger-2

The problem is that Dagger can't see dependency (**DataManager**) that I want to use in **ActivityModule** which is defined in **ApplicationModule**. I have pretty standard Dagger2 project structure:

**ActivityComponent.java:**

```
@PerActivity
@Component(dependencies = ApplicationComponent.class, modules = ActivityModule.class)
public interface ActivityComponent {
    void inject(WelcomeFragment fragment); // HERE ERROR IS COMING FROM
}
```

**ApplicationComponent.java:**

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = ApplicationModule.class)
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    Context getContext();
}
```

**ActivityModule.java:**

```
@Module
public class ActivityModule {

    private Activity activity;

    public ActivityModule(Activity activity) {
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Provides
    CompositeDisposable provideCompositeDisposable() {
        return new CompositeDisposable();
    }

    @Provides
    @PerActivity
    WelcomeViewModel provideWelcomeViewModel(DataManager dataManager, CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable) {
        return new WelcomeViewModel(dataManager, compositeDisposable);
    }
}
```

**ApplicationModule.java:**

```
@Module
public class ApplicationModule {

    private final Application application;

    public ApplicationModule(Application application) {
        this.application = application;
    }

    @Provides
    Context provideContext() {
        return application;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    DataManager provideDataManager(DataManagerImpl dataManager) {
        return dataManager;
    }

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    Retrofit provideRetrofit() {
        return new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(<API_ADDRESS>)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
}
```

**PerActivity.java:**

```
@Scope
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface PerActivity {
}
```

The error shows up in **WelcomeFragment** where I'm trying to *inject* **WelcomeViewModel** that needs **DataManager** and the message is indicating that Dagger can't see where **DataManager** is *Provided*:

```
Error:(12, 10) error: <PACKAGE_NAME>.data.DataManager cannot be provided without an @Provides-annotated method.
<PACKAGE_NAME>.data.DataManager is injected at
<PACKAGE_NAME>.di.module.ActivityModule.provideWelcomeViewModel(dataManager, …)
<PACKAGE_NAME>.views.welcome.WelcomeViewModel is injected at
<PACKAGE_NAME>.views.welcome.WelcomeFragment.viewModel
<PACKAGE_NAME>.views.welcome.WelcomeFragment is injected at
<PACKAGE_NAME>.di.component.ActivityComponent.inject(fragment)
```

**WelcomeViewModel.java:**

```
public class WelcomeViewModel extends ViewModel {

    @Inject
    public WelcomeViewModel(DataManager dataManager, CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable) {
        super(dataManager, compositeDisposable);
    }

(...)
}
```

**WelcomeFragment.java:**

```
public class WelcomeFragment extends BaseFragment {
    @Inject WelcomeViewModel viewModel;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_welcome, container, false);
        getActivityComponent().inject(this);
        init();
        return view;
    }
(...)
}
```

**DataManagerImpl.java:**

```
@Singleton
public class DataManagerImpl implements DataManager {
    private Retrofit retrofit;

    @Inject
    public DataManagerImpl(Retrofit retrofit) {
        this.retrofit = retrofit;
    }
(...)
}
```

I can only say that I'm using the same Dagger structure in 2 other projects and always it was working without any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use [Component dependencies](https://google.github.io/dagger/api/2.10/dagger/Component.html#component-dependencies) you need to expose the `DataManager` in the `ApplicationComponent` to the `ActivityComponent`

```
@Singleton
@Component(modules = ApplicationModule.class)
public interface ApplicationComponent {
    Context getContext();

    DataManager exposeDataManager();
}
```

Comment: Wow, I had no idea I need to do that. Thank you so much!

Comment: You could use [Subcomponents](https://google.github.io/dagger/subcomponents) instead - then you don't need the expose methods.